# What's a suitable implementation of equals() for a class with no fields?

Tags: java, equals

Let's say I have a class with no fields, but a few methods. For example a class which only implements an `interface`:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface
{
    @Override
    public void someMethod(int param) {...}

    @Override
    public int getSomeValue(OtherClass param) {return ...;}
}
```

Now I want to override `equals()` for this. Can I always return `true`, by arguing that "since the objects don't have any state, they are always equal"?

An implementation like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (null == other || !(other instanceof SomeClass))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:** Since some people asked about the intention behind this, I'm going to elaborate more on the context in which this question arose:

This class is an event-listener. I instantiate and pass it as a listener to an async request, along with some other data, encapsulated in an Object named `Config`.

In other words, I have a class named `Config` which is composed of `SomeClass` and some other data.

```
public class Config
{
    SomeClass someClass;
    int otherData;
    //...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {/*???*/}
}
```

Actually I wanted to implement `equals` for this `Config` class (Because I want to prevent repeated requests). But since one part of the `Config` is this instance of `SomeClass` I was wondering what to do with that.

**Side question**: If the `SomeClass` is a nested class and have implicit reference for its enclosing class, what to do then? (In my context, it is.)

Comment: Why override `equals` at all for such a class? You are probably not going to store instances of that class in a Set or in keys of a Map, are you?

Comment: I would say they are equal if and only if they are of same class, e.g. if I had `class OtherClass extends SomeClass` and override some methods, those should not be equal.

Comment: Normally I advocate the opposite (to avoid static methods), but if a class has **no** fields whatsoever; then I am wondering why you would need to create instances of that class in the first place.

Comment: You might want to check class for equality, rather than just instanceof. This seems to be some kind of strategy pattern and you probably don't want your SomeClass to be equal to somebody's SomeClassSubclass, which extends you class overriding some of the methods.

Comment: You are better off with the default implementation. IMHO, making the assumption that all instances of a class are equal doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Jägermeister Maybe in order to have objects which fit the said `interface` and which can be passed to respective methods.

Comment: You must ask yourself, why do you want to compare this class with other instances? The class has no state, so i dont see any reason to override the default Object implementation.

Comment: @Eran, Jägermeister, tak3shi, I added the reason for my question. I'd like to have your opinion now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just returning `true` is a bad implementation, as it will mean that any instance of your class is equal to **any other object**, which is probably not what you intended. Moreover, it will break `equals`' general contract of commutativity, as `mySomeClass.equals("Mousa")` will return `true` while `"Mousa".equals(mySomeClass)` will return `false`.

As `SomeClass` has no state, implementing its `equals` method is a matter of taste. Having any two `SomeClass` instances be equal to each other is a reasonable choice, although the implementation you suggested can be improved. As `other instanceof SomeClass` will return `false` if `other` is `null`, the method could just be rewritten as

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other instanceof SomeClass;
}
```

Also, you should note that in order to maintain the general contract of two *equal* objects having the same `hashCode()`, you should override that method too. E.g.:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return SomeClass.class.hashCode();
}
```

On the other hand, it's also perfectly reasonable to decide that since `SomeClass` has no state, the only way two objects can be equal to each other is if they both point to the same instance (i.e., the behavior of the `==` operator). This approach is taken by another famous stateless class you may know from the JDK - `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @matt Good point. Using `getClass()` probably isn't resilient enough. I edited my answer to improve it.

Comment: About your first paragraph, I have considered that at my implementation: `if (null == other || !(other instanceof SomeClass)) return false;`

Comment: @mousa The first paragraph was addressing the commutative property of equals. Eg. a.equals(b) if and only if b.equals(a). It has nothing to do with the null check. They also pointed out that your null check is pointless. `if (null==other || !(other instanceof SomeClass)) return false` can be replaced with `return other instanceof SomeClass;` The null check is redundant.

Comment: @matt, OK thanks. So apart from the specific cases of `null` or being object of other classes, you and the author, agree with the `true`, right?

Answer (score 4):

That is a semantical question: what does it mean to have two objects of this class? (Might it even be useful to implement it as a singleton?)

If they can be used interchangeably, they can indeed be considered equal. (Don't forget to override `hashCode()` then.) But as well, you can keep the original definition which comes from `Object`.

Comment: I agree. Take a step back for a moment... do you really need more than one instance of a state-less class? Why are you putting multiple copies in a `Collection`, or why else are you comparing them?

Comment: Thanks, I see what you say. Actually this changes my point of view and can think better. Also I added more information about the context of question and I would like to have your opinion on my specific case.